# Создание ассоциативного массива PHP где ключ = значение

Tags: массивы, xml, циклы

Подскажите пожалуйста, как можно создать массив где ключ равняется значению. Все элементы массива уникальны, дубли отсутствуют.
Сам массив заполняется перебором XML таблицы.
Буду очень благодарен за помощь.

Comment: Смысл делать такое? Используйте тогда "не ассоциативный массив" и работайте с ним как угодно

Comment: foreach($citys->data->item as $cityname){
            $mista[$cityname->Description] = $cityname->Description;
        }

Comment: Что я делаю не так. Возвращается пустой массив.

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach($citys->data->item as $cityname){
            $cname = (string)$cityname->Description;
            $mista[$cname] = $cname;
}
```

Так заработало. Всем спасибо, кто откликнулся.